# How does knn-query hybrid search interact with rescore?

Tags: elasticsearch, knn

[According to the kNN documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html#_combine_approximate_knn_with_other_features):

> You can perform hybrid retrieval by providing both the knn option and a query. This search finds the global top k = 5 vector matches, combines them with the matches from the match query, and finally returns the 10 top-scoring results. The knn and query matches are combined through a disjunction, as if you took a boolean or between them... The score of each hit is the sum of the knn and query scores.

[And according to the rescore documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/filter-search-results.html#rescore):

> The query rescorer executes a second query only on the Top-K results returned by the query and post_filter phases

What is the expected behavior if we include `knn`, `query` and `rescore` all at the same time? Will the rescore take as input the top `window_size` results from the `query` alone? Or will it take as input the top results from the query-knn hybrid?

Our desired behavior is to rescore the top 400 results from the hybrid-output. If simply specifying `knn`, `query` and `rescore` does not do this, is there some other way to accomplish this?